RotatingFIleHandler rotates files without exceeding maxBytes
LOGGING['handlers']['file'] = {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'awx.main.utils.handlers.CompressedRotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(LOG_PATH, 'debug.log'),
        'maxBytes': 1024*100,
        'backupCount': 5
    }

I have written this piece of code for file logging in my django application, however each of the log files do not exceed the given maxBytes. When the first file exceeds the maxBytes it immediately creates 5 new log files with name .1 .2, etc and zips them(I am using custom handler which overrides the RotatingFileHandler's doRollover class). I am also attaching CompressedRotatingFileHandler class code for reference.
class CompressedRotatingFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def doRollover(self):
    """
    Do a rollover, as described in __init__().
    """
    if self.stream:
        self.stream.close()
        self.stream = None

    if self.backupCount > 0:
        for i in range(self.backupCount - 1, 0, -1):
            sfn = f"{self.baseFilename}.{i}"
            dfn = f"{self.baseFilename}.{i + 1}"
            if os.path.exists(sfn):
                if os.path.exists(dfn):
                    os.remove(dfn)
                os.rename(sfn, dfn)
        dfn = self.baseFilename + ".1"
        if os.path.exists(dfn):
            os.remove(dfn)
        os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)

        # Gather log files
        log_files = [
            f"{self.baseFilename}.{i}"
            for i in range(1, self.backupCount + 1)
            if os.path.exists(f"{self.baseFilename}.{i}")
        ]

        # Get count of existing backup zip files
        nzip_backups = len(glob.glob(f"{self.baseFilename}.backup.*.zip"))

        # Check if the number of backup log files has reached the limit
        if len(log_files) == self.backupCount:
            zip_filename = f"{self.baseFilename}.backup.{nzip_backups + 1}.zip"
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "w") as myzip:
                for fn in log_files:
                    if os.path.exists(fn):
                        myzip.write(fn, os.path.basename(fn))
                        os.remove(fn)
                        time.sleep(1)  # Optional delay to ensure the file is removed

    self.mode = 'w'
    self.stream = self._open()

